# RegisterForActivityResult callback is not triggered after changing Fragment Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, callback, fragment

Fist of all, I am using bottomNavigation which has five fragments on the MainAcitvity .

The problem is down below.

I am using RegisterForActivityResult for gallery image in the **fragmentA**.
when I use that  before changing to other fragments, It's perfectly fine.

However, after changing to different Fragments
and back to the fragmentA then call RegisterForActivityResult again, the callback is not triggered.

when my MainActivity is with in Condition1 **I had a problem.**

When my MainActivity is with in Condition2 RegisterForActivityResult **callback was fine.**

**condition1**----------------------------------------------------------------------

I Initialized fragment variables in the ***onCreate***  on MainActivity , and BottomNavigationListener as well.

---

**Condition2**----------------------------------------------------------------------

I Initialized fragment variables in the ***onStart*** on MainActivity , and BottomNavigationListener as well.

---

**Does anybody know why?**

** Problem Code ↓ condition1**

```
class Main : AppCompatActivity() ,BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //viewbinding
    private lateinit var binding: Activity4MainBinding


    //fragment Verables
    private lateinit var homeFragment :Fragment_Home
    private lateinit var liveFragment :Fragment_Live
    private lateinit var boardFragment :Fragment_Board
    private lateinit var chatFragment :Fragment_Chat
    private lateinit var mypageFragment :Fragment_Mypage


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = Activity4MainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

   
        homeFragment = Fragment_Home.newInstance()
        liveFragment = Fragment_Live.newInstance()
        boardFragment = Fragment_Board.newInstance()
        chatFragment = Fragment_Chat.newInstance()
        mypageFragment = Fragment_Mypage.newInstance()
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        //first fragment when the App started
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_layout, 
        homeFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()

    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

    }

  
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
       
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, homeFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.live -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, liveFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.board -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, boardFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.chat -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, chatFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.mypage -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, mypageFragment).commit()
            }
        }
        return true
      }

}
```

** Working Code ↓ condition2**

```
class Main : AppCompatActivity() ,BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //viewbinding
    private lateinit var binding: Activity4MainBinding


    //fragment Verables
    private lateinit var homeFragment :Fragment_Home
    private lateinit var liveFragment :Fragment_Live
    private lateinit var boardFragment :Fragment_Board
    private lateinit var chatFragment :Fragment_Chat
    private lateinit var mypageFragment :Fragment_Mypage


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = Activity4MainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

   
        homeFragment = Fragment_Home.newInstance()

        //first fragment when the App started
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_layout, 
        homeFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()

    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        liveFragment = Fragment_Live.newInstance()
        boardFragment = Fragment_Board.newInstance()
        chatFragment = Fragment_Chat.newInstance()
        mypageFragment = Fragment_Mypage.newInstance()
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

  
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
       
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, homeFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.live -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, liveFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.board -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, boardFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.chat -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, chatFragment).commit()
            }
            R.id.mypage -> {

                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, mypageFragment).commit()
            }
        }
        return true
      }

}
```

FragmentA code↓

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    //  binding
    lateinit var binding:FragmentABinding


    //for instance from outside of the fragment

      fun newInstance() : FragmentA{
      return FragmentA()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    }

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
     savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   
        binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
     binding.button.setOnClickListener{
    requestImagesFromGallery.launch("image/*")}
    }

  private val 
   RequestIamgeFromGallery=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
    //If callback is triggered, returned uri set into the Imageview
        binding.mypageImage.setImageURI(uri)
    }
}
```

Please give me some comments why those Fragments instance in the MainActivity onStart work, but onCreate is not working. Also is it ok if I use the condition2?